# How to modify endblock content in symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to modify the content of the end block in the symfony. When I did inspect element at that time it is showing in model-footer. How can I modify footer content.
[image: Footer Content]

I want to change name from save order to save

Comment: welcome to the stack overflow. Maybe you could take a look at the instructions on how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (as this question of yours really doesn't provide enough information to say much). But as a generic advise, maybe you can search for the term "Save Order" from your project to find the template?

Comment: your question is not clear , can you explain more and show your code please .

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but I think I know what you mean ...
Normally you have a block {% block footer%} {% endblock%} in your base.html.twig. To add content, go to the specified view by adding ...

```
{% block footer%}
 // Your HTML Content
{% endblock%}
```